# Json spring : output is xml but I want JSON

Tags: java, json, xml, spring, spring-mvc

All code is working fine, but output generated using code is XML not json, can somebody help me how can I get JSON format output from this code.

Here is Controller class

```
package spring;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus; 
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;

@RestController

public class Main {

@RequestMapping(value="/main",method = RequestMethod.GET,headers =    {"Accept=text/xml, application/json"},produces = "application/json")
@ResponseBody()
public  ResponseEntity<Student> f()
    {

        Student s=new Student();
        s.setName("Nikesh Joshi");
        s.setAge(21);
        s.setId(1);
        return new ResponseEntity<Student>(s, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
    }
```

Here is model class,

```
package spring;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement; // I dont know which one to use

import com.sun.xml.internal.txw2.annotation.XmlElement; //this or above

@XmlRootElement
public class Student implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 2646831820313826686L;
private String name;
private int id;
private int age;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public int getAge() {
    return age;
}
public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}
}
```

web.xml have simple mapping to the the spring front controller Dispatchers servlet.

Output is in XML Format like this 
[image: Output]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">


    <!-- Detects annotations like @Component, @Service, @Controller,    @Repository, @Configuration -->
   <context:component-scan base-package="spring"/>

   <!-- Detects MVC annotations like @RequestMapping -->
   <mvc:annotation-driven/>
   </beans>
```

Comment: have you tried removing the `@XmlRootElement` annotation from your model class?

Comment: By request JSON and not XML.

Comment: If I remove Root XMl then 406 error on browser

Comment: do you have jackson/gson or any such library in classpath to convert to json

Comment: Please Tell me How can I request JSON

Comment: @Deinum he already has the produces as application/json. is that not sufficient ?

Comment: Yes I have JackSon library in my classpath and lib forlder

Comment: post your view resolver configuration

Comment: Please help me, I am really Frustrated wth this error

Comment: I have posted view resolver configuration as well.

Comment: @nikesh - the beans xml file does not help.. what is there in the spring package that is being scanned?? we need the code that configures the view resolvers.

Comment: There is no code for view resolver , Because I am returning object from it, if any view resolver is required then please tell me what to write in it.please give answer Man, I need your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What type of client are using using to request your service. If you are using a browser it favours xml ahead of json(Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8 for firefox). Spring uses the Accept header for content negotiation. Your service has both xml and json enabled because both JAXB and JSON are on the classpath.

The best way is to use a request parameter or file extension to influence content negotiation rather than depending on Accept header which is difficult to control for all clients. To do so add the following to your application context

```
<mvc:annotation-driven content-negotiation-manager="contentNegotiationManager" />
<bean id="contentNegotiationManager" class="org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean">
<property name="favorPathExtension" value="true" />
<property name="favorParameter" value="true" />
<property name="mediaTypes" >
<value>
json=application/json
xml=application/xml
</value>
</property>
</bean>
```

To access your service for xml you can use for example http://host:port/context/resource.xml using extension or http://host:port/context/resource?format=xml using request parameter

To access your service for json you can use for example http://host:port/context/resource.json using extension or http://host:port/context/resource?format=json using request parameter.

NB. produces attribute of @RequestMapping is not used for content negotiation but for narrowing handler methods

Comment: <mvc:annotation-driven content-negotiation-manager="contentNegotiationManager" /> Is generating error.

Comment: Did you remove your origional mvc:annotation-driven element. Please provide the details of the error you are now getting. What version of spring are you using?

Comment: vc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'content-negotiation-manager' is not allowed to appear 
 in element 'mvc:annotation-driven'.....       This is error I am getting I am suing spring 4.1

Comment: You are using the mvc namespace version 3. Omit version numbers instead to use latest version like
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

Comment: Please can you send code on netparam.nikesh.joshi@gmail.com . I dint found any mvc namespace version

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the response content type:

```
response.setContentType("application/json");
```